# Drupal 8 views date range filter lost when other exposed filters applied

Tags: date, datetime, drupal-views, drupal-8, date-range

In Drupal 8, I have a View name Events, where **Content type:** Events. 
with **two Exposed Filters**, `Event Type` and `Event Date`. The Event Date has operator `is between` with values `Now` and `+2 years`. So when the user first visits the page it shows all events from `now until the next 2 years` default.

But, however when a user changes the `Event Type` filter, the `Event Date` filter is lost and Events with `Any` option are shown.

Is this is an issue? because, all the old events from the past are displayed.

Does anyone know how can I keep the date range filter on after additional filters are applied?

I'm using the datetime_range module, and I've patched it with #60 at https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2786577#comment-11860104 to enable date range filtering with views.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you select the `default value` radio button correctly, if you are choosing `grouped filters`